# Adding label to the end of HTML Range slider

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently implementing a range slider and have a label at the start of the slider which is positioned just above the slider. This label represents the low end of the scale. Now i need to add a label in the same position at the end of the slider to represent the highest end of the scale. However, i can only get the label to appear at the start of the scale but underneath. I'm using Bootstrap for CSS.

```
<div class="container">
      <label for="agitated">Agitated</label>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" id="fader">
      </br>

      <label for="happy">Happy</label>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" id="fader">
      </br>

      <label for="tired">Tired</label>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" id="fader">
      </br>

      <label for="scared">Scared</label>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" id="fader">
    </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right but maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/okyf0omz/) helps you ?

Comment: See that's what i tried originally. As clearly that is the most obvious thing to try. However, this is what it produces for me.

http://imgur.com/162oODQ

Comment: Maybe this something like this can fit : https://jsfiddle.net/okyf0omz/3/

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<label for="happy" class="pull-left">Happy</label>
<label for="" class="pull-right">Sad</label>
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" id="fader">
</br>
```

Something like this? If thats the points, just use the bootstrap class `pull-left` and `pull-right` for each label.

Here is example:

http://jsbin.com/ziluwuv/1/edit?output

Answer (score 5):

Just a heads up for anyone wondering why the answer given by @Denisx isn't working with Bootstrap 4.0 . Use `float-left` and `float-right` rather than `pull-left` and `pull-right`.